# Handling key error in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, python-3.6

The below function parses the cisco command output,stores the output in dictionary and returns the value for a given key. This function works as expected when the dictionary contains the output. However, if the command returns no output at all the length of  dictionary is  0  and the function  returns a key error . I have used  `exception KeyError:` But this doesn't seem to work.

```
from qa.ssh import Ssh
import re

class crypto:
    def __init__(self, username, ip, password, machinetype):
        self.user_name = username
        self.ip_address = ip
        self.pass_word = password
        self.machine_type = machinetype
        self.router_ssh = Ssh(ip=self.ip_address,
                              user=self.user_name,
                              password=self.pass_word,
                              machine_type=self.machine_type
                              )

    def session_status(self, interface):
        command = 'show crypto session interface '+interface
        result = self.router_ssh.cmd(command)
        try:
            resultDict = dict(map(str.strip, line.split(':', 1))
                              for line in result.split('\n') if ':' in line)
            return resultDict
        except KeyError:
            return False
```

test script :

```
obj = crypto('uname', 'ipaddr', 'password', 'router')
out =  obj.session_status('tunnel0')
status = out['Peer']
print(status)
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test_parser.py", line 16, in <module>
    status = out['Peer']
KeyError: 'Peer'
```

Comment: You are looking for a safe `get` method. Try using `out.get('Peer', None)`. And the second argument to`.get` is the default that you would like.

Comment: @kiran.koduru im curious to know why exception KeyError: is not working

Comment: The line `out = obj.session_status('tunnel0')` ran ok and generated a dict. Is it possible that the `except KeyError` is only thrown when the dict is being built, not when it is referenced by `out['Peer']`?

Comment: @mjsqu no in this case,dictionary is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This explains the problem you're seeing.

The exception happens when you reference `out['Peer']` because `out` is an empty dict. To see where the KeyError exception can come into play, this is how it operates on an empty dict:

```
out = {}
status = out['Peer']
```

Throws the error you're seeing. The following shows how to deal with an unfound key in `out`:

```
out = {}
try:
    status = out['Peer']
except KeyError:
    status = False
    print('The key you asked for is not here status has been set to False')
```

Even if the returned object was `False`, `out['Peer']` still fails:

```
>>> out = False
>>> out['Peer']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    out['Peer']
TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable
```

I'm not sure how you should proceed, but dealing with the result of `session_status` not having the values you need is the way forward, and the `try:` `except:` block inside the `session_status` function isn't doing anything at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

The `KeyError` did not happend in the function `session_status`,it is happend in your script at `status = out['Peer']`.So your `try and except` in `session_status` will not work.you should make a `try and except` for  `status = out['Peer']`:

```
try:
    status = out['Peer']
except KeyError:
    print 'no Peer'
```

or :

```
status = out.get('Peer', None)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your exception is not in the right place. As you said you just return an empty dictionary with your function. The exception is trying to lookup the key on empty dictionary object that is returned `status = outertunnel['Peer']`. It might be easier to check it with the dict get function. `status = outertunnel.get('Peer',False)` or improve the test within the function session_status, like testing the length to decide what to return `False` `if len(resultDict) == 0`