# How can I check error in 'if' condition to make decisions?

Tags: python, dictionary, error-handling

Assume, I have a dictionary:

```
myList ={1:'One', 2:'two', 3:'three'}
```

And my code is like:

```
if myList[4]:
   last = myList[4]
else:
   last = myList[3]
```

This returns a `KeyError`.

I know about the `myList.get(4,'Something')`. But I'm looking for something else.

Is there something like:

```
if 'KeyError' myList[4]:
   last = myList[3]
else:
   last = myList[4]
```

A method like this is explained here https://realpython.com/python-keyerror/ . I tried. But it still raises a `KeyError` when `myList[4]` does not exist. Can someone help me to find what am I missing here?

```
myList={1:'one', 2:'two', 3:'three'}

if 'keyError' in myList[4]:
    last = myList['3']
else:
    last = myList['4']

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 4
```

The `try...except` method is not appropriate for me. it makes my code lengthy and slower.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling key error in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44814651/handling-key-error-in-python)

Comment: I'm gonna go for a downvote for these comments: _The try...except method is not appropriate for me. it makes my code lengthy and slower_ and _But I'm looking for something else_. I don't understand what you want and on what basis you refuse the 5 answers given to you.

Comment: @NicolasGervais you really didn't understand, That's why you failed to realize why I didn't accept those answers. See, the answer I marked answer (for your learning purpose). By the way, collecting reputation on stackoverflow is not my vision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a list of a dictionary's keys with `myList.keys()`, so you could do this:

```
if 4 in myList.keys():
    last = myList[4]
else:
    last = myList[3]
```

Based on what you are doing, you might also be interested to know that you can get the length of a dictionary using `len(myList)`, so what you are doing (with incrementing keys starting at `1`) could also be done more generically like this:

```
last = myList[len(myList)]
```

I think you should rename `myList` to `myDict`. It is not a list. It is a "dictionary", a.k.a. a `dict`.

Finally, try to avoid using `try-except` blocks where you can. If you are going to use `try-except`, it is best to catch a particular error (like `KeyError` as you mentioned). To see the correct way to catch a KeyError, see the answer by @jeanpierre-fisher (helpfully edited by @ann-zen).

Comment: Great! I have should think of it earlier. Thanks a lot. Marked your answer as solution. But, can you explain, what's wrong with `if keyError in myList[4]:` ? I'm concerned about myList/myDict fact. Thanks though.

Comment: When you say `"keyError" in myList[4]`, the first that happens is the python "interpreter" will evaluate `myList[4]`, which "raises" a KeyError Exception. Since this exception is raised, the code stops. it will not check if "keyError" is a key in the dictionary (which is what that code does).  To see the correct way to catch a KeyError, see the answer by @jeanpierre-fisher (helpfully edited by @ann-zen).

Answer (score 1):

You can catch it using a try except block:

```
myList = {1:'one', 2:'two', 3:'three'}

try:
    last = myList[len(myList)]
except KeyError as e:
    print('KeyError: ', e)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it inside a try statement and deal with the error:

```
try:
    last = myList[4]
except KeyError:
    last = myList[3]
```

Answer (score -2):

The simplest safe way, if you don't want to use try except block (which is recommended best practice) is to just use this:

```
last = myList[len(myList)]
```

Comment: This is an exact subsection of my answer

Comment: I wrote this 34 minutes ago and you duplicated mine 8 minutes ago. Look above This was in my first answer 34 minutes ago

Comment: Oh you are right. I am sorry. Sincere apologies. I did not intentionally duplicate your answer. We independently wrote the exact same line of code. I will undo my downvote.

Comment: No worries. We’re you able to remove the downvote? Thank you, JP

Comment: Sorry, I thought I did but it seems I cannot undo the vote. To make up for it, I voted up 2 other good answers you have on other questions.